# Horizontal ProgressBar Color Change

Tags: android

I have declared the progress bar in xml.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbSurvey"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lblSkipSurvey"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:maxHeight="10dip"
    android:minHeight="10dip"
    android:progress="50"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

At runtime, I am changing the progressBar's progress's color to white.

```
 pbSurvey.setProgress(progress);
 pbSurvey.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
 pbSurvey.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

Every time it's showing only dark green color. No theme and style has been set for progress bar. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this piece of code:

```
    public static final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 };
    final ShapeDrawable pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(Constants.roundedCorners, null, null));
    final LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, displayWidth / 2, 0, ctx.getResources().getColor(
            color.aa_blue), ctx.getResources().getColor(color.aa_red), android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    pgDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(3);
    pgDrawable.getPaint().setDither(true);
    pgDrawable.getPaint().setShader(gradient);

    ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    par.setProgressDrawable(progress);
    par.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal);
```

It's doing a shaded color progress bar, You could use it or just set equal colours on both side. I guess your error is that of using `pbSurvey.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter()` while you should call `pbSurvey.setBackgroundResource()`

Comment: To just fill the color, do we need to use drawable ? What is "pgDrawable" in your code?

Comment: pgDrawable is a ShapeDrawable, I added it to the code

Comment: Thanks Shine. It worked. But wtf is that just to set the color, we need to do these kind of things...

Comment: code should be a little more simple removing the shaded thing. Try removing the setShader() call once it's working

Answer (score 0):

I used this to change color of progressBar, no gradient simple color change.

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

`R.color.colorPrimary` is there in my respective folder, needed to be changed accordingly.